# update x value using slider matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to draw a graph, which show the progress of a chemical reaction. The progress itself (time or reactionsteps) should be changeable using a slider.
The code I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)
fig.canvas.set_window_title('Reaktionsfortschritt')

t0 = 0
t = np.arange(0, t0, .5)
k0 = 0.17
a = np.exp(- k0 * t)

l, = plt.plot(t, a, lw=3, color='crimson')
plt.axis([0, 20, 0, 1])

axrs = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor='lightblue')
srs = Slider(axrs, 'Reaktionsschritte', 0, 20, valinit=0)

def xval(*args):
    x = srs.val
    t = np.arange(0, x, 0.5)
    #l.set_ydata(np.exp(- 0.6 * t))
    #plt.plot(t, a)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

srs.on_changed(xval)

plt.show()
```

As far as I understand the plot-range (t) is updated using the xval-function. However, there is no plotting of the graph.
I tried both replotting using `plt.plot(t, a)` as well as `l.set_ydata(...)`.

## edited

Ok, so now I added a second function (b) that describes product formation. I added the function also in the same way to the update-function. As a result I get a very strange behaviour: using the slider, I can plot only in positive x-direction, e.g. there I no going back. Once the graph is drawn, it won't 'undraw' when reducing the slider value. Any suggestion why that is?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)
fig.canvas.set_window_title('Reaktionsfortschritt')

t = np.arange(0, 0, .5)
k0 = 0.17
a = np.exp(- k0 * t)
b = 1 - np.exp(- k0 * t)
# plot
l, = plt.plot(t, a, lw=3, color='crimson')
m, = plt.plot(t, b, lw=3, color='dodgerblue')
plt.axis([0, 20, 0, 1])
plt.grid(True)

axrs = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor='lightblue')
srs = Slider(axrs, 'Zeit', 0, 20, valinit=0)

def update(x):
    t = np.arange(0, x, 2)
    ax.lines.pop(0)  # remove previous line plot
    ax.plot(t, np.exp(- k0 * t), lw=3, color='crimson')
    ax.plot(t, 1 - np.exp(- k0 * t), lw=3, color='dodgerblue')
    fig.canvas.draw()

srs.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Notice that `t` is an empty array. What do you want to change with the Slider? Seems like you want to change the number of plotted points, so change xdata and ydata.

Comment: I edited my answer to make it work for your edit. Hope this gives insight in what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have time on the x-axis and want to change the maximum time of your plot that is created by the same function every time, I came up with this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)
fig.canvas.set_window_title('Reaktionsfortschritt')

t0 = 0
t = np.arange(0, t0, .5)
k0 = 0.17
a = np.exp(- k0 * t)

l, = ax.plot(t, a, lw=3, color='crimson')
plt.axis([0, 20, 0, 1])

axrs = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])
srs = Slider(axrs, 'Reaktionsschritte', 0, 20, valinit=0)

def update(x):
    t0 = x
    t = np.arange(0, t0, .5)
    ax.lines.pop(0)  # remove previous line plot
    ax.plot(t, np.exp(- k0 * t), lw=3, color='crimson')  # plot new one
    fig.canvas.draw()

srs.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

See what it does when changing the Slider value and let me know if this is what you wanted it to do.

---

**To your edit:**
When you add a second plot, you have two `lines` objects. Try to print `ax.lines` directly after you run the code (before touching the Slider) and see that it really is a list of two `lines`. Then call `ax.lines.pop(0)` and see that one element is popped from the list. That's what the above code does, it removes lines from the `axes` object `ax` every time you touch the Slider (because then `update` is called), which after calling `fig.canvas.draw()` leads to vanishing of previous plots. If you now touch the Slider once, then two new `lines` are added to `ax` and only one is removed. This is why you think there is no going back.
So if you now added a second plot, you just have to pop twice from the list `ax.lines` with `ax.lines.pop(0)` and the code works fine ;-)

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Thank you very much for the quick answer and your help.

Comment: Works just fine. Thank you very much for your explanation.