# In python, is it possible to create a plot and modify it dynamically?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Suppose I have a code such as:

```
xvalues = range(10000)
yvalues = []
for x in xvalues:
    y = do_calculation(x)
    yvalues.append(y)
    plt.plot(xvalues,yvalues)
```

This code produces 10,000 different plots. I want to create a single plot that is updated in each iteration, so that the viewer sees an animation of how the graph is plotted.

Is this possible in python?

Comment: Yes, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450311/update-x-value-using-slider-matplotlib/44450742#44450742).

Comment: The example below is good for animation.  There's also interactive plots you can do with plotly but i dont think that's what you want

Comment: What did prevent you from searching for ["matplotlib animation"](http://www.google.de/search?q=matplotlib+animation)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on you example, it seems that you were thinking about making an animation with simple `for` loop. Yes you can do it with `time.sleep()` so that the animation is visible. The key is to use `line.set_data()` and `fig.canvas.draw()` to update the plot. For example:

```
import time

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 100
do_calculation = np.sin
xsteps = list(range(N))
xvalues = []
yvalues = []

fig = plt.figure()
l, =plt.plot(xvalues, yvalues)
plt.xlim(0, 2 * np.pi)
plt.ylim(-1, 1)

for i in xsteps:
    x = i / N * 2 * np.pi
    xvalues.append(x)
    yvalues.append(do_calculation(x))
    l.set_data(xvalues, yvalues)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    time.sleep(0.01)

plt.show()
```

You can also the `animation` module. That might give you more and easy access to settings for fine tuning your animation. You can also save your animation as a video. Official examples are [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/index.html). The following is a small example I made which is closer to your example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

do_calculation=np.sin
N = 100
xvalues = []
yvalues = []

fig = plt.figure()
l, =plt.plot(xvalues, yvalues)
plt.xlim(0, 2 * np.pi)
plt.ylim(-1, 1)

def update(num, xs, ys, line):
    x = num / N * 2 * np.pi
    xs.append(x)
    ys.append(do_calculation(x))
    line.set_data(xs, ys)
    if num == N - 1:
        xs.clear()
        ys.clear()
    return line,

line_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, N, fargs=(xvalues, yvalues, l), interval=10)

plt.show()
```